# find a and b in algebraic expression

Tags: polynomials

I have been given the following expression$$(x+a)(x^2+bx+3)=x^3+3x^2+5x+6$$I must determine the values of a and b.

I am unsure where to begin with this one, I have tried expanding brackets on LHS and grouping like terms (get stuck at that point). I have also tried subtracting 6 from both sides, then factoring out x on RHS, and then using the quadratic formula to find x, however this leaves a discriminant of $\sqrt{-11}$ so I also get stuck at that point.

any help showing the methodology and the steps to find a and b would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Expand on the left, and identify the coefficients in front of $x^3,x^2,x$ and the constant term.

Comment: This is an equality of polynomials, not an equation to solve for $x$. Now, two polynomials are equal when coefficients are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Expand the LHS. Then compare the coefficients. This should give your answer.

Comment: yes this makes sense. Do you agree the answer is $a=2$ , $b=1$?

Comment: absolutely. perfect.

Answer (score 1):

expanding the left Hand side we get
$$x^3+x^2(a+b)+x(3+ab)+3a$$ ánd this must be $$x^3+3x^2+5x+6$$ and now compare the coeffictions

Comment: thanks i see now its just a case of comparing coefficients, no need to find x. i got $a=2$   $b=1$. is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

expanding the left Hand side we get
$$x^3+x^2(a+b)+x(3+ab)+3a$$ ánd this must be $$x^3+3x^2+5x+6$$ and now compare the coeffictionts
then you will get
$$b=2,1$$
and $$a=1,2$$ respectivelly

Comment: great I understand this, however can you explain why you have two values for a and b?

Comment: after comparison i got two equations 
$$a+b=3 and 3+ab=5$$
one is quadratic so the roots of quadratic equations are two
further if you to how then 
$$b=3-a $$
put this in $$3+ab=5$$
you will get the two values of a
then use these values of a in $$b=3-a$$